# Regarding some symbols in set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I came across this interesting statement that defines the aleph numbers:
$$\aleph_{n+1} = \bigcap \{ x \in \operatorname{On} : | \aleph_n | \lt |x| \}$$
However, I do not understand a couple of symbols. First of all, what does that massive intersection sign mean, and what set is $\operatorname{On}$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{On}$ is presumably the proper class of all ordinals, so $\bigcap\{x \in \mathrm{On} : |\aleph_n| < |x|\}$ is the intersection of all ordinals whose cardinality is strictly greater than that of $\aleph_n$. Since the ordinals are well-ordered with respect to inclusion, this means that $\bigcap\{x \in \mathrm{On} : |\aleph_n| < |x|\}$ is the least ordinal whose cardinality is strictly greater than $|\aleph_n| (= \aleph_n)$, i.e., $\aleph_{n+1}$.

This can be extended to all alephs $\aleph_\alpha$ and may also be used to define $\aleph_\alpha$ for nonzero limit ordinals $\alpha$ as well (namely, for $\alpha$ a nonzero limit ordinal, $\aleph_\alpha = \bigcap\{x \in \mathrm{On} : (\forall \beta < \alpha) \, (|\aleph_\beta| < |x|)\}$).

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by an intersection of ordinals?

Comment: @MathGeek I'm not certain where your confusion is. Perhaps in how ordinals are being considered as sets (in case you might be considering them as isomorphism classes of well-ordered sets)? Is it that $\{x \in \mathrm{On} : |\aleph_n| < |x|\}$ is a proper class? What the intersection of a family of sets is?

Comment: Yes, I think my confusion is in ordinals being considered sets. Even if they are, however, I cannot see how there can be an intersection between them since they are all different.

Comment: Also, I don't know what the intersection of a family of sets is.

Comment: @MathGeek We're implicitly using the von Neumann definition of ordinals here. Namely, a set $x$ is a *von Neumann ordinal* if it is strictly well-ordered by $\in$ and is transitive (i.e., if $y \in x$ and $z \in y$, then $z \in x$; said another way, $y \in x$ implies $y \subseteq x$). Some of things one can prove: 
- The class $\mathrm{On}$ of (von Neumann) ordinals is strictly well-ordered by $\in$ and well-ordered by $\subseteq$. 
- Every well-ordered set $(W, \leq)$ is order-isomorphic to exactly one von Neumann ordinal ordered by inclusion, $(\alpha, \subseteq)$.
...

Comment: - If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals, then $\alpha \in \beta$ if and only if $\alpha$ is order-isomorphic to a (proper) initial segment of $\beta$, and likewise $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ if and only if $\alpha$ order-embeds into $\beta$ (in which case it does so as a (potentially non-proper) initial segment of $\beta$. As such, $\min(\alpha, \beta) = \alpha \cap \beta$.

If $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of sets, then $\bigcap\mathcal{F} = \{ x \mid (\forall A \in \mathcal{F}) \, x \in A \}$, so the largest set (with respect to inclusion) contained in every member of $\mathcal{F}$. ...

Comment: ... In the same vein as $\min(\alpha, \beta) = \alpha \cap \beta$, given any family of von Neumann ordinals $\mathcal{F}$, the intersection of that family is exactly the minimum element of the family.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132826/discussion-between-mathgeek-and-hayden).

Comment: You need to understand '$\bigcap$' long before the rest. Without that, and an understanding of how ordinals are defined in set theory, it's a bit facetious to be asking about alephs.